# Why is using random module in the pandas assign method returns the same number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Here is a small code snippet which I though should create 2 dataframe columns (*randomNumber, randomNumber2*) which are populated with random integer choosen from uniform distribution in 1 to 100 range.

```
import random 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n = 1000
df_test = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(n))

df_test = df_test.assign(randomNumber = random.randint(1,100))

df_test['randomNumber2']  = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=n)  

    
print(df_test.shape)
df_test.head()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdZH1.png)

Why, when using assign() method and a function from random module all dataframe rows have the same value of *randomNumber* column?

I understand that the quickest way to populate dataframe column with random numeric value is by using built-in numpy method, however I can't understand why the "assign" method doesn't work here. I thought that in this scenario random.randint(1,100) function should be called for each df_test row.

I also can't find the answer to my question in the pandas official documentation.
Could someone explain what's happening and what am I missing, or point me towards an explanation?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Why, when using assign() method and a function from random module all dataframe rows have the same value of randomNumber column?" Because `randomNumber = random.randint(1,100)` happens **before `df_test.assign` is called**. You won't find anything about this in the Pandas documentation because it is not the job of that documentation to teach how to use Python.

Comment: The argument to a function is evaluated just once, when the function is called, not every time the function needs to use the parameter. So only one random number is passed, and it's used for all the assignments.

Answer (score 1):

`random.randint` returns a single integer, and when you assign an integer to a column, that single integer is repeated for each row.
`np.random.randint` returns an array of integers which becomes the new column values. Same name, different functionality. But that's the same for everything. `+` to integers adds two integers. `+` for numpy arrays add the entire arrays.

Note, this doesn't have anything to do with `.assign` specifically. Had you `df_test = df_test.assign(randomNumber = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=n))`, you would have seen a column of random numbers.